# How to set up Schema-aware XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm trying to look at using types to select elements that are subtypes, so I have a test document with subtypes of xs:integer and xs:float.

How do I tell XQuery to use the types defined in my schema?

(It might be relevant that I'm using oXygen and Saxon-SA)

Input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test-inherit.xsd">
    <int>4</int>
    <rest-int>5</rest-int>
    <rest-float>6</rest-float>
</root>
```

WXS Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="int" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="rest-int" type="rest-int"/>
                <xs:element name="rest-float" type="rest-float"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="rest-int">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="10"></xs:maxInclusive>
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"></xs:minInclusive>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="rest-float">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="10"></xs:maxInclusive>
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"></xs:minInclusive>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

XQuery:

```
for $integer in doc("test-inherit.xml")//element(xs:integer)
return <integer>{$integer}</integer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the schema in your XQuery. Also, if you want the loaded document to be validated against that schema (and schema types assigned to document nodes accordingly), you need to use the `validate` expression:

```
import schema default element namespace "" at "myschema.xsd";
for $integer in (validate { doc("test-inherit.xml") })//schema-element(int)
return <integer>{$integer}</integer>
```